# Controller in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I’m planning to create an order entry transaction, using 30 vusers I’ll be running it and will be saving the order numbers in a param list (I hope this is possible).

Now, I need to create a transaction to verify orders, using the param list I’ve created above, My question is if I use 30 vusers how would they pick the order numbers? Once 30 vusers are started is there a possible conflict of two users picking the same order number?

Please explain how this works and the best possible solution to achieve the above task.

Comment: Please read the help section about parametrization: VuGen > Script Workflow > Parameterizing > Parameterizing - Overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a parameter to a file you are going to have all sorts of issues

1. Managing lock for multiple users on the same file, likely across load generators.  This alone can turn this one file into a bottleneck for your test as everyone waits for arbitrated access to the lock on the file
2. Parameter files are loaded into RAM at the beginning of the test, so you will not be able to use the parameters within the context of the same test.

Workaround:  You could validate with a simple web_reg...() function within the same business process.   This would be the lightest weight method.

If you need to share between virtual users where user A creates and user B validates then you need a queue or service to pass the information between.  In such a case HP offers the Virtual Table Server as a service for just this type of operation.  You can, however, leverage any external queue service, even using a managed service such as Amazon Simple Queuing Service, for this type of storage in between users where one user "pushes" the data and another "pops" it for validation.

Comment: As per your comments i have used "web_reg_save_param" and it works - First enter the order save the order number in the param and the next action would be to go approve the order. In the approval process i have two options "Approve" or "Cancel" 

Is it possible to write code in such a way the controller can do 70% approval and 30% cancel ? That way i can get max coverage. 

Or, should i create a new action for Cancel? Even if i did how would the Controller or Vugen understand which action to choose between "approve" or "cancel"? 

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It is C.  So long as you can write code in C then the answer is yes that code can be constructed for 70/30.  You might also want to review the training material for the use of blocks in the run time settings.   You also appear to be commingling two business functions (which would be conducted by two different types of users) in the same physical test code.  This would cause you to fail an audit of your test on the issue of separation of business processes by role. Keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

You could try LoadRunner VTS component. It allow you saving you parameters. And if you want to avoid conflict for these parameter, you can retrieve a parameter from VTS. This means read and delete the first line of the table. And you could append it at the end of the table if you want. More detail could be found from VuGen Help->Additional Compoenents->Virtual Table Server

Comment: To learn more about VTS, check out this blog post: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/The-New-Virtual-Table-Server-VTS-in-LoadRunner-11-52/ba-p/6069435#.VTYoapPNI-o

Answer (score 1):

In Loadrunner you cannot dynamically update the parameter list during test execution.(Reason: Parameter files will be saved in Load agent machines during test execution)

You can save the "Order Entry" to a simple text file.
In Verify Order you can create a parameter *"paramname"* with parameter type "Vuser ID" and read the file data with respect to Vuser ID.

Eg: if *"paramname"* value is 2 then read the line number 2 from text file that you have created earlier.